# Force dummy HDMI plug to have custom screen resolution

Tags: hdmi, resolution, screen-sharing

I control my old 2012 retina MacBook Pro from my 2020 MacBook Pro using Apple's Remote Management feature. I keep the old MacBook with the lid closed to save space physically. This typically forces the laptop to go to sleep unless you have an external display connected (which I don't). There have been many attempts over the years (both successful and unsuccessful) to write programs that keep the MacBook Pro running in clamshell mode without needing an external display connected.

One such program is [Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12). When using it on the old MacBook, however, I noticed that there would be large gaps in iStat Menus, which suggested that it was sleeping periodically even though Amphetamine was enabled.

[image]

Instead of messing around like this, I decided to get a dummy HDMI plug to emulate a display being connected, to make the Mac think that I was in clamshell mode. This seems to have worked, but the resolution looks absolutely horrible on newer Mac's `1440x900@2x`-scaled screen. I have no option to choose this resolution in System Preferences on my old Mac either:

I had the idea of downloading the popular SwitchResX and choosing `1440x900@2x` as my resolution. However, while SwitchResX has options for `1280x800@2x` (which is a bit small and causes black bars around my screen) and `1440x900@1x` (which is not retina resolution), it has no option for `1440x900@2x` which I am looking for.

[image]

See the 1280x800@2x resolution with black bars here: https://ibb.co/84FXXt5

Setting a custom HiDPi resolution of `1440x900@2x` does not seem to work either. As soon as I activate it my screen sharing stops and ...

I tried using a different app, appname, but it also doesn't seem to have the correct HiDPi resolution I'm looking for.

[image]

Is there a way to force my old MacBook Pro to think that the resolution of my dummy plug is `1440x900@2x`, so that it takes on this resolution while in clamshell mode and thus looks good while screen sharing on my newer MacBook Pro?